# Show element with attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<input type="radio" name="group2" test="one" value="Water"> Water
<input type="radio" name="group2" test="two" value="Beer"> Beer<br>

<div style="display: none" test="one">aaaaaaa</div>
<div style="display: none" test="two">bbbbbbb</div>
<div style="display: none" test="one">ccccccc</div>
```

I would like: if i click on radio Water with attribute test="one" then should show me all div with attribute test="one". How can i make it with jQuery?

**LIVE:** http://jsfiddle.net/hRCXV/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
    var test = $(this).attr("test");
    $("div[test]").hide();
    $("div[test='" + test + "']").show();
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/hRCXV/3/)

Please bear in mind that creating your own attributes as you have here is not valid. If you're using HTML5 you should consider using the `data` attribute to store whatever information you need associated with each element.

Answer (score 2):

Attach a label to the `Water` text, and a click handler using the attribute selector:

```
<label for="option1">
    <input type="radio" name="group2" id="option1" test="one" value="Water"> Water
</label>

<script>
$('label').click(function() {
    // Logic tells me that you want to only show the test elements whose
    //   attribute matches the selected radio element; Hide the previous ones:
    $('div[test]').hide();

    // Get test value:
    var test = $('#' + $(this).attr('for') ).attr('test');

    $('div[test="' + test + '"]').show();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input [value="Water"]').click(function() {
   $('[test="one"]').show();         
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hRCXV/1/

```
$("input[type=radio][value=Water]").click(function()
                                           {
                                               $("[test=one]").show();
                                           });​
```

Answer (score 1):

I belive this is something that you are looking for?

```
​$(':radio[name="group2"]')​.click(function(e){    
    var test = $(this).attr('test');
$('div[test]').hide();
$('div[test='+test+']').show();
    });​
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var yourAttributeName = 'test';
    var allDivs = jQuery('div['+yourAttributeName+']');

    jQuery('input['+yourAttributeName+']').click(function(){
        allDivs.hide().filter('[' + yourAttributeName + '=' +     jQuery(this).attr(yourAttributeName) + ']').show();    
    })
    //check the init checked
    .filter(':checked')
    //and fire click event to filter
    .click();
});
```